# Pass function to jQuery .ready() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am currently making use of [Simon Willson's addLoadEvent](http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/26/addLoadEvent/) function to add functions that I want to run after the load event.  I ran into a problem wherein the the function I passed to the addLoadEvent function referenced a div that had not yet been loaded by the DOM and so my action (showing the div) did not do anything.  When I changed to using the jQuery $(document).ready function, the div has been loaded by the DOM and I can execute actions with it (make it show up).

So, a couple questions.  Why is my function being executed before the DOM has completed loaded using the above function?  Is there a way to delay it?  The other alternative that I can think of is passing in a function to a jquery equivalent:

```
function jqueryAddReadyEvent(myFunc)
{ 
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        //execute already existing functions
        //add a new function to the ready event
        myFunc();
    }
}
```

When I try the above code, I get a javascript error "myFunc is not a function".  Is there a way to generically pass in a function to the jquery ready function and have it execute? Equivalent to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    funcA();
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    funcB();
}
...//more of the same
```

Replaced with the following:

```
jQueryAddReadyEvent(funcA);
jQueryAddReadyEvent(funcB);
```

Comment: If you are getting this error, then you are not passing a function to `jqueryAddReadyEvent` (http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/A2Pm3/).

Comment: What argument are you passing to jqueryAddReadyEvent? Are you sure it is a function?

Comment: You could always use a `setTimeout` although I don't recommend it. I dare say `$(document.read(function() { funcA(); funcB(); });` Is the best way to go. Also, try `console.log(arguments)` in your `jqueryAddReadyEvent` to find out more about your params (if you haven't looked up `console.log`, you'll like it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
$(document).ready(myFunc);
```

to attach functions to the DOM ready event. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/padtE/

Comment: And/or use the shortcut `$(myFunc)`.

Comment: @Jeremy: What exactly does that mean? **What** does not work? If you don't provide your code, we cannot help. The method itself works, as the jsfiddle clearly shows.

Comment: @Felix Kling: the function that I am passing into this that shows my divs does not work.  If I pass in something simple like an alert, I see the alert popup.  If I have my div showing function by itself in a $(document).ready() area, it shows my div. But passing in the div showing function into the example above does not show the div.

Comment: Walking through the function again, my divShow function is called but it is called before the DOM has finished loading (getting the div to show returns null). Because this generic form function lives in a separate js file, could that affect when the ready event is fired?

Comment: @Jeremy: As I said, we cannot help you much if you don't post the code. Apparently you are not passing the function correctly, you are calling it too early. Make sure you don't *call* the function where you have to pass it. The `ready` event will always be fired when the source is completely parsed. Just make sure you include the file *before* you call/pass the function.

Comment: If the showDiv function is running before DOM ready, be sure to pass the function by reference, and not like $(document).ready(myFunc()). Whether the showDiv function is in an external file or not doesn't matter

Comment: @Felix, yeah I was thinking of using the shorthand in the example, but I think I'd rather it be the longhand if it's in a wrapper function, so people can easily tell what it does at a glance, meanwhile $(func); isn't very descriptive

Comment: @alex thanks for the help.  When I changed the function to be passed by reference instead, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you will require many functions to be added then I suggest you do the following:

```
Create an array that will old all the functions you want to call.
Add functions to that array as you please.
In the .ready(function() { ... }) call every function in that array.
```

You're set.

Answer (score 0):

```
function jqueryAddReadyEvent(myFunc) {
    $(myFunc);
}

jqueryAddReadyEvent(function() {
    alert('hello world');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/UzMLE/

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct to me. Most likely you are calling it with something not a function.

Btw you can shorten this to:

```
var jqueryAddReadyEvent = $(document).ready
```

or just use $(document).ready() directly for the same effect, as it specifically does what you want to do, run functions after the load, and is actually shorter.

```
$(document).ready(funcA);
$(document).ready(funcB);
```